# Android listener GCM or ?

Tags: android

Ещё раз задам тот же вопрос, для того что бы уточнить, однажды тут я спрашивал как сделать нотификацию в приложении андроид от внешнего сервера, предлагали использовать push notification от GCM.

Задача в том что бы слушать изменения в базе данных mysql внешнего сервера в интернете через клиент приложение. Если произошли изменения то уведомить пользовательское приложение.

Мне хочется советов какие ещё могут быть варианты ?
уточню тех задание.

1. Mysql сервер с таблицей в базе данных с количеством сообщенией в одной из ячеек.
2. Apach сервер с PHP где идёт подключение к этому Mysql серверу и обращение к базе данных, где PHP скрипт возвращает кол-во этих сообщений в ячейке
3. Android Клиент приложение которое обращается к Apach серверу дёргая файл php который читает базу и возвращает кол-во сообщений.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы при изменении кол-ва сообщений в самые кротчайшие сроки отдать клиент приложению Android уведомление об этом.

Comment: У вас 6 вопросов, на которые вы получили 8 ответов. Ни один ответ вами не принят и даже не проголосован как понравившийся. Если так и дальше пойдет, то вам просто перестанут отвечать.

Answer (score 1):

Самое первое, что нужно понимать, что скорость отдачи пользователю и нагрузка на сервер - взаимосвязанные вещи. Чем быстрее Вы хотите доставлять сообщения, тем больше нагрузка.

Поэтому Вы должны определиться с термином "в кратчайшие сроки". Может быть 20 секунд будет предостаточно? В таком случае нужен скрипт, который каждые 20 секунд будет делать `select count(*) from table` и если есть новые записи - рассылать.  Или даже просто записывать в текстовый файл. Все клиенты просто читают его. Любой апач или nginx легко отдаст сотню раз в секунду  текстовый файл.

Вариант номер два. Когда приходит клиент проверяется, когда делался последний запрос. Если это было больше 20 секунд назад и никто запрос не делает - делаем запрос, иначе ждем очереди.    Если последний запрос был меньше 20 секунд назад - просто отдаем ответ.

Это все называется кешированием и широко применяется. В любом случае, время кеширования (то есть те 20 секунд) можно поменять на нужные.